# Appending string variable into xml

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working with 3 classes.I have various text fields in every class.The data entered from first class get saved into a xml file.Similarly ,how can the data entered from second class and third class should get append into the same xml file that of the first class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for your data model. Set it up using the Singleton pattern. Import it into all of your classes. This way your data model is available for appending, manipulation, saving, etc anything you want.

That's the simple answer. Now.. how to do it.

Here's [one approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like), there are others (Google's your friend).